# Can I burn Ubuntu 16 in a DVD with Ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, iso, burning

What I have is a DVD with Ubuntu 14 burnt via Brasero.
What I want is Burn Ubuntu in this same DVD.
I'm guessing it will have a menu like the boot loader menu where I can choose which distro I want to install.
is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a rewritable DVD (DVD-RW), then Brasero will allow you to wipe or clean the disc, allowing you to write an image onto it like it was new. The disc will have to be fully erased before more data could be written.

If you are using a non-rewritable DVD (DVD-R, DVD+R, etc), then you cannot use it more than once. In that case, you can install 16.04 via a USB instead. A simple program to write .iso images to USB is UNetbootin, which can be installed with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

I'm sure this program can also be found in the software center too.